# Python - Adding Graphic to TKInter Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I am a python beginner so sorry for the probably very simple question.  I am trying to make a game using the TKInter canvas.I have tried various versions but decided I want to use the image of a wizard as my character. This is the code I have so far which creates the canvas but not sure how to add the image.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Wizard:
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image = tk.PhotoImage(file="wizard.jpg")

class Magic_land:
    def __init__(self, start):
        self.start = start
        self.start.title("Magicland Game")
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(start, width=600, height=600, bg="#17becf")
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.create_text(200, 100, text="Welcome to Magical Land! Help the wizard collect    all the spell items!",
                            fill="red")


# Run the main event loop
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = tk.Tk()
    game = Magic_land(start)
    start.mainloop()`
```

I have tried adding the PIL package (as thats what google told me to do!) but wont work.

Here is the code - any advise gratefully received! ps. using PYCharm